# How to execute bash code for each iteration of the find command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Using this will perform a grep for each file found:

```
find . -name "$FILE" 2>null | xargs grep "search_string" >> $grep_out
```

But what if I want to execute custom code for each file found, rather than executing a grep? I would like to parse each file my own way, which is motivation for doing this. Could I write the code in the pipe? Should I execute a separate script using the pipe? Can I expand the pipe's scope to execute the next lines in the code before finding the next file?

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to go about it, each with pros and cons.  In addition to anubhava's inline method, you could use the -exec flag and a custom script.  Example:

```
find . -name "$FILE" -exec /path/to/script.sh {} +
```

Then write `/path/to/script.sh` so that it accepts an arbitrary number of file arguments.  Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "$@"; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

This approach affords reuse over the inline method, but is less efficient.

The `{} +` business on `find` passes multiple files to a single invocation of the script, rather than firing up the script multiple times -- saves a bit on process overhead.  If you want the script to execute fresh for each single file, use `{} \;` instead (and just ue "$1" in your script, no looping needed).

The `"$@"` bit keeps the file names quoted, important for the cases where your file names have white space in them.

Comment: -execdir is better than -exec if other process share the filesystem.

Comment: @user2987828: "better" is an opinionated word. If you want only the base file name, and not the path, and don't mind the chdir() overhead, and need exceptional process isolation, go for it -- it is the safest (most paranoid) option.  But a few things.  First, on MacOS X, -execdir and + don't work together.  Second, [chdir() overhead can add as much as 10%](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/fast04/tech/full_papers/radkov/radkov_html/node10.html) to total execution time.  Third, you cannot use execdir if "." is in your path on Linux.  I could go on.  Suffice to say, there are pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just clicked +1 to your answer for that comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `while loop` like this **in BASH**:

```
while read f; do
    # process files here
    echo "$f"
done < <(find . -name "$FILE")
```

**For using it with `sh` (which doesn't support process substitution):**

```
find . -name "$FILE" | while read f; do
    # process files here
    echo "$f"
done
```

**[Read more about process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)**

Comment: I'm trying this, but I get: 
`syntax error near unexpected token '<'`

Comment: Make sure to execute above code in BASH. You seem to be using sh

Comment: Is there a way to do it with sh?

Comment: Yes let me update the answer for `sh` version but you tagged your question with `bash` :)

Comment: `find . -name "$FILE" | while read f; do
    { # process files here
    } < /dev/null ; echo "$f"
done` will work in bash

Comment: Edited my answer which is also in comments by @user2987828 (thanks!)

Comment: Yes! This was very helpful, thank you. I'm now modifying my file processing to get this tool working.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "$FILE" 2>null -execdir /path/to/script.sh {} \;
```

This way, no more need to make a for loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-exec` option (instead of `xargs`) :

```
find . -name "$FILE" -exec ./test.sh {} \;
```

With a script `test.sh` which contain whatever you want. For example :

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "name=$1"
grep "string" "$1"
$ cat test
string
string2
test
$ sudo find . -name "test" -exec ./test.sh {} \;
name=./test
string
string2
```

Comment: -execdir is better than -exec if other process share the filesystem.